# How to use OpenAPI 3.0 in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, swagger, openapi

The OpenAPI Specification (fka Swagger Specification) is at version 3 - see https://swagger.io/specification

However, the [npm swagger package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger) uses version 2 of the spec.

How do I go about using the Swagger framework with Node.js but using version 3 of the OpenAPI Specification? Is there an official npm package for OpenAPI 3.0? Or is my thinking totally wrong? Maybe Swagger is now a standalone desktop app or something and is not installed with npm anymore? (Similar to how Postman is a standalone desktop app.)

Comment: ATOW it appears Swagger 3 is only available via Swagger Hub although the new swagger-editor should implement Swagger 3 eventually